# Adding nodejs modules to Laravel projects Error: RPERM Mkdir

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm-install

I am trying to add nodejs modules to Laravel project. while writing command 'install npm' on git bash the following error message is shown: 
$ npm install
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Git\user'
    at Error (native)
Could anyone suggest me the problem with it and its solutions

Comment: Either manually give permissions to your user account or make sure to run Git Bash as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

You can either manually give permissions to your user account or make sure to run Git Bash as an administrator. 
Running it as administrator is the best option